# How to disable all td tag in jsp using css

Tags: css, jsp

I have a form that is in jsp at one condition the user click to view the form. When the form is render the information contain in the form should not be editable all the td should be visible but should not be editable.

for example:-

```
 <table width="600" align="center" >
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_left_b" width="30%">Company Name:</td>
                        <td width="60%" height="25"><input type="text" size="28" value="${com.companyName}" id="companyName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_left_b" width="30%">Hotel Name(Display Name):</td>
                        <td width="60%" height="25"><input type="text" size="28" value="${com.hotelName}" id="hotelName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_left_b" width="30%">Country:</td>
                        <td width="60%" height="25"><input type="text" size="28" value="" id="country"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="td_left_b" width="30%">City:</td>
                    <td width="60%" height="25"><input type="text" size="28" value="${com.cityName}" id="cityName"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_left_b" width="30%">NeighbourhoodName:</td>
                        <td width="60%" height="25"><input type="text" size="28" value="${com.neighbourhoodName}" id="neighbourhoodName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_left_b" width="30%">Street Name:</td>
                        <td width="60%" height="25"><input type="text" size="28" value="${com.streetName}" id="streetName"/></td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

The above information i am putting through spring MODEL ATTRIBUTE in respective td. i dont want to be editable the information.
Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSP. Please provide the HTML and give us an idea of what you've tried.

Comment: you might have done wrong in JavaScript or Jquery .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable Tablecolumns. You have to disable evere input in your table.

Comment: you means at each every td i need to add disable atttribute.

Comment: you cannot disable td's. You have to disable INPUT-Tags (where you enter the data) with the disabled-attribute.